# sql server parsing xml from select query

Tags: sql-server, xml

There is a remote sql server db which I can only access through a web service, passing a sql text to it. The service wraps the passed in sql text into a select statement and returns the result of the query.

For example if I want to execute :

`select employeeName, caseNumber from AppTable`

I pass into the service `'select employeeName, caseNumber, 12344 vendorId from AppTable'`, the service will actually execute following:

`select * 
from (select employeeName, caseNumber, 12344 vendorId from AppTable) s where s.vendorId = 12344`

The requirement is to get all cases by each employee's boss, so it would be something like

`select employeeBoss, count(caseNumber) from AppTable group by employeeBoss`

The problem is that the employeeBoss is not stored in the remote database, I will have to pass this information in through the webservice.
So lets assume I have an xml like text that I could pass to the service:

```
<Employee>
   <Name>John Doe</Name>
   <EmployeeBoss>Bill G</EmployeeBoss>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
   <EmployeeBoss>Gordon B</EmployeeBoss>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <Name>Derek Edward</Name>
   <EmployeeBoss>Gordon B</EmployeeBoss>
</Employee>
```

Is there any way to parse the XML in a select statement so that I could get the desired result? I am thinking to get something like this

> select x.EmployeeBoss, count(distinct caseNumber)
>     from AppTable a
>   inner join EmployeeFROMXML x on x.Name = a.EmployeeName
>   group by x.EmployeeBoss

but I don't have the EmployeeFROMXML table, I just have a string like XML. So how can I transform the string like XML into a sql table to be able to join with the existing AppTable only with a help of SELECT statement. (no variable declarations allowed since I can use only the web service which only supports select statements)

Comment: Correct, fixed...thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
with xmlDat as (--read as xml
select cast(
'<Employees>
    <Employee>
       <Name>John Doe</Name>
       <EmployeeBoss>Bill G</EmployeeBoss>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
       <EmployeeBoss>Gordon B</EmployeeBoss>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <Name>Derek Edward</Name>
       <EmployeeBoss>Gordon B</EmployeeBoss>
    </Employee>
</Employees>' as xml) e
)
,emp as (--tabulate
select t.v.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)') Name,
t.v.value('EmployeeBoss[1]','varchar(100)') EmployeeBoss
from xmlDat cross apply e.nodes('Employees/Employee') t(v)
)--and use
select emp.EmployeeBoss, count(distinct caseNumber)
from emp
inner join AppTable a on emp.Name = a.EmployeeName
group by emp.EmployeeBoss
```

### Update

The same without CTE

```
select emp.EmployeeBoss, count(distinct caseNumber) from 
(select t.v.value('Name[1]','varchar(100)') Name,
t.v.value('EmployeeBoss[1]','varchar(100)') EmployeeBoss
from  
(select cast(
'<Employees>
    <Employee>
       <Name>John Doe</Name>
       <EmployeeBoss>Bill G</EmployeeBoss>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
       <EmployeeBoss>Gordon B</EmployeeBoss>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
       <Name>Derek Edward</Name>
       <EmployeeBoss>Gordon B</EmployeeBoss>
    </Employee>
</Employees>' as xml) e
) xdat  cross apply e.nodes('Employees/Employee') t(v)) emp
inner join AppTable a on emp.Name = a.EmployeeName
group by emp.EmployeeBoss
```

Comment: this is closer to the desired result, however I cannot use CTE's since the webservice is wrapping the select with another select so I end up with something like select * from (with xmlDat....) which won't work.

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can select xml values using xquery funcitons

```
SELECT 
[xmlColumn].value('(/Employee//EmployeeBoss/node())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as boss
FROM AppTable a
INNER JOIN xmlTable on [xmlColumn].value('(/Employee//Name/node())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as name = a.EmployeeName
```

This query isn't tested, but I have used the `.value()` function before to interact with XML columns and it served me well.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the xmlTable and xmlColumns. I only have a text in XML format.

Comment: You can convert a NVarChar column to XML with `Convert(XML, columnName)`.

Comment: I don't have a nvarchar column nor a table to select from. I just have a string formatted as XML...how to I convert this to a sql table only by using a select statement. ( I know I can use OpenXML but you need to declare a xml handle, call stored proc etc....but I can only use select statement since I run through a web service).